# How do i perform the desired operation If one of the command button is OK and the other is CANCEL

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

Can anyone tell me How do i do certain task based on the command button options.
I have a Userform where user submits his data and it has 2 command buttons one is OK and the other is CANCEL. I have to exit when user clicks CANCEL and continue the Process when user clicks ok

```
             file_name=userform1.textbox1.value
```

This is how we can get the data of the text box into our functions but what is the way to know which command button key is pressed ? Becuase if i press OK or CANCEL the operation is still being performed. I have tried like these

```
       value=userform1.commandbutton1.value 
       value2=userform1.commandbutton2.value
```

not working. I even tried these

```
      commandbutton1_click() \\ this is the OK command button 
      call main
      end sub
      commandbutton2_click() \\ this is the CANCEL command button
      end sub
```

I have tried To call the main sub_routine from the OK sub routine But it says main routine not found becuase I have written these codes in the thisworkbook.and the commandbutton1_click routine is inside the Userform1 module 
SO how do i make it work? I hope you understood where I'm Stucking up.Thank you in advance

Comment: do you want the operation to happen while the form is on screen or only after it has closed and they have clicked ok?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to keep the main method outside of your userform, you can try something like this, based on the example given by @cularis

```
' This way you can keep your code in ThisWorkbook    
' I would recommend creating a new module. 
' You can name your module whatever you'd like. 

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    ThisWorkbook.main
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    Unload Me
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click() 'should be called cmdOk
    main
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click() 'should be called something like cmdCancel
    Unload Me
End Sub

Private Sub main()
    'DO PROCESSING
End Sub
```

Do you call `main` on `Form_Load()` or `Form_Activate()` or anything like this? When clicking Cancel, the above unloads the form. When clicking Ok, it starts the processing. There is not more to it.